# I want to use query in rails just like:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I face a problem during selection with order. It is not working. Query:

```
Order.select("order_at BETWEEN ? AND ?","#{Time.now}","#{Time.now - 20.day}")
```

The issue I am facing is I have some other stuff with this as well.

```
Order.joins('left joing with some association').group('orders.id').select("SUM(CASE WHEN association.created_at BETWEEN '#{Time.now.utc}' AND '#{(Time.now - 20days).utc}' THEN association.quantity ELSE 0 END) as total_qty")
```

Now I want this `Time.now.utc` to be pass in as external parameter like this

Order.select("order_at BETWEEN ? AND ?","#{Time.now}","#{Time.now - 20.day}")

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to interpolate, in Ruby, you need double quotes:

```
string = 'Hey'
puts "#{string} you" # "Hey you"
```

That works for strings, but you don't need to wrap a Time object in quotes, it doesn't need to be converted to string.

And instead using select, which only select certain attribute (columns) from models (tables) being specified in the query, you should use where, and note the order of dates in the query matters:

```
Order.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.now, Time.now - 20.days)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to try in this case is `find_by_sql` method. `select` method is responsible only for `SELECT` params of query. Rewrite your code as:

```
Order.find_by_sql("order_at BETWEEN ? AND ?",'#{Time.now}','#{Time.now - 20.day}')
```

This should work

PS: But this is not a good solution for ActiveRecord. You can do the same with:

```
Order.where(order_at: (Time.now - 20.days)...Time.now)
```