# Passing date parameters to a sql select query in rails (QueryMethods)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, psql

I am working with the brakeman gem (which identifies possible security issues in Ruby on Rails code). We have a scope which uses joins, group and select and I need to update the select part of the query. This scope looks something like the below. I am putting content of the scope here on product model.

```
Product.joins('LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.product_id = products.id')
  .group('products.id')
  .select(
    "SUM(CASE WHEN orders.order_at BETWEEN '#{start_date}' AND '#{end_date}'" \
    " THEN orders.qty ELSE 0 END) as qty, products.*"
  )
```

Now If i try to change query like this

```
Product.joins('LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.product_id = products.id')
  .group('products.id')
  .select(
    "SUM(CASE WHEN orders.order_at BETWEEN ? AND ?" \
    " THEN orders.qty ELSE 0 END) as qty, products.*",
    '#{start_date}',
    '#{end_date}'
  )
```

It gives me syntax error where I have `?` I have also tried some other ways with group and having but it didn't worked for me. I am using postgres sql with rails 4.1.8
Is their any way I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

This is the error

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?"
>     LINE 1: SELECT
>   SUM(CASE WHEN orders.order_at BETWEEN ? AND ? AND ord

Comment: There's no enough info. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531438/i-want-to-use-query-in-rails-just-like/47531725#47531725) there's a similar unattended question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can also get rid of the CASE statement with a where clause:

[checkout range conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions)

```
Product
  .joins('LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.product_id = products.id')
  .where(orders: {order_at: start_date..end_date})   # range condition
  .group('products.id')
  .select("SUM(orders.qty) as qty, products.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re right to use the `?` syntax, but your call to `select` needs part of it split out into a call to `where` intead.

Also, you’re converting your dates to strings (e.g., `'#{start_date}'`). That prevents the called method from being able to handle, and format, the values as dates. Instead, just pass the raw dates (e.g., `start_date`).

```
Product
  .joins('LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.product_id = products.id')
  .where('orders.order_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_date, end_date)
  .select("SUM(orders.qty) as qty, products.*")
  .group('products.id')
```

You could also redo the `where` call based on daino3’s answer (`.where(orders: {order_at: start_date..end_date})`).

## Reasoning

It’s critical to not embed parameters directly in `where` (or related) calls. Doing so opens your code up to major security risks, known as [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because a remote user could potentially put any arbitrary string of data triggering all manner of dangerous calls being performed on your database.

That’s why you should always do `where('various sql things ?', parameter)` instead of `where("various sql things #{parameter}")`.

For more on the subject of passing in parameters to Rails sql calls like this, check out the [official Rails Guide on the Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions).

Comment: `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN orders.order_at BETWEEN ? AND ? THEN orders.qty  ELSE 0 END) as total_qty, products.*, '2017-11-28 05:00:00.000000', '2017-11-29 04:59:59.999999' FROM "products" LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.product_id = products.id GROUP BY products.id`

This is the query which is generated and it has the same error. I think ? should be replaced by date but it is not and I don't know why.

Comment: That's usually the correct thing to do, but unfortunately the `select` method doesn't take parameters that way, so you need to either sanitize them yourself before embedding them in the string, or find another way to construct your query (such as how @daino's answer shows).

Comment: Oh, yeah — using `where` instead of `select` should fix that.